# How to remove focus from Text block by clicking outside it

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to create a program using tkinter. The goal is to remove the focus from Text widget by clicking somewhere outside it. I've tried this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
txt = tk.Text(root)

txt.pack()
root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: root.focus_set())
#txt.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: txt.focus_set()) <- it doesn't work with this too
root.mainloop()
```

But this just sets focus to root every time i press `B1` (in both variants). Help, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could detect the current widget under the mouse coordinates and use this to determine if you should focus on root or not:

```
def click_event(event):
    x,y = root.winfo_pointerxy()                   # get the mouse position on screen
    widget = root.winfo_containing(x,y)            # identify the widget at this location
    if (widget == ".text_widget") == False:        # if the mouse is not over the text widget
        root.focus()                               # focus on root

text_widget = tk.Text(root, name="text_widget")
text_widget.pack()

root.bind("<Button-1>", click_event)
```